A small uncountable cardinal
Let $\kappa$ denote the minimum cardinality of a set $F$ of functions $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ with the property:

For any function $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ and any infinite set $A\subseteq\mathbb N$, there is a function $f\in F$ such that $\{n\in A:g(n)\le f(n)\}$ is infinite.

Plainly $\mathfrak b\le\kappa\le\mathfrak d$ in the notation of Cichoń's diagram. Is  $\kappa=\mathfrak b$ or $\kappa=\mathfrak d$ provable in ZFC? If not, is there an established notation for this cardinal $\kappa$?
The "unboundedness namber" $\mathfrak b$ is the minimum cardinality of a set $F$ of functions $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ with the property:

For any function $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ there is a function $f\in F$ such that $\{n\in\mathbb N:g(n)\le f(n)\}$ is infinite.

The "dominating number" $\mathfrak d$ is the minimum cardinality of a set $F$ of functions $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ with the property:

For any function $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ there is a function $f\in F$ such that $\{n\in\mathbb N:f(n)\lt g(n)\}$ is finite.


For simplicity, let's restrict attention throughout to nondecreasing functions. (This doesn't change the value of $\kappa$.)
For $g$ a nondecreasing function and $A$ an infinite set of naturals, let $g_A(x)=g(x')$ where $x'$ is the smallest element of $A$ which is $\ge x$. If $f$ is nondecreasing then $f$ escapes $g$ on $A$ (= $\{a\in A: f(a)\ge g(a)\}$ is infinite) iff $f$ escapes $g_A$ in the usual sense (= $\{n\in\mathbb{N}: f(n)\ge g(n)\}$ is infinite).
In particular, this means that any escaping family satisfies your condition, and so $\kappa=\mathfrak{b}$.
